# Where can a new freelancer find people to work with?

Tags: group-freelancing

Offline and online, how can I determine what places someone new to freelancing should frequent to get a solid start; Specifically, someone looking to partner with other freelancers?

How can I determine what kinds of places (both online and locally) would be good to help me find potential partnerships, and sources for projects?

How can I determine what types of network groups, sites, etc that should be avoided as they seem to promise more value than they actually deliver (for the investment in time or money they require)?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, sorry, but questions like this don't really fit the Q&A format very well. They tend to attract mostly spam, and answers that are posted are difficult to vote to the top since every answer is equally valid. Try a google search for "Freelancing groups/meetups" in your area. Good luck! :)

Comment: Hi Muhammad, [Tim Lytle](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users/820/tim-lytle) and I edited your post to focus on the why and how, things that could help other freelancers too. As such, I've reopened this post and hope you get good answers. I also tweeted it to my followers using the `share` link below the post, so we'll see how it goes. Sorry it took so long to reopen this and hope this helps!

Comment: Muhammad: how can I contact you directly?

Comment: http://goo.gl/forms/QbZETPt13e I just made it for us. Send email, ill reply using my email. This way all of our emails remain safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that I am in the same situation as you are. I study all kind of stuff especially in the computer-related area and I entertain the idea of working as a freelancer myself. So, just out of curiosity, I did a search on Google to find out about the ways one freelancer could use to promote himself and I have found a LOT of useful websites out there, most of them being websites where you can post your resume or to create a profile. Some of them are general, others are centred on niche activities.

So my advice is this: just do a Google search with the terms - freelancers websites - and you should see several of the most important freelancer websites and also a bunch of article titles sounding like this: "10 (or 15, or 50) great websites for freelancers". In those articles you will find lots of freelancing websites and also interesting information about each one of them.

Soon you will realise that not only you can easily promote yourself as a freelancer, and thus you can easily find new people to work with, but also the ways are so many that you will have to choose only several of them, only several preferred websites. Or, if you have the time and the patience to upload your resume and to be active in all of them, that's no problem!

Comment: Welcome to Freelancing, Cristiana.  Answers that amount to "Google is your friend" are not overly helpful... perhaps you could summarise some that you found useful AND WHY?

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. Indeed, I find interesting the freelance world and I intend to explore it more. Now, back on subject. I know that an answer like: "go son, do a google search and you'll find your nirvana" may sound ironical and shallow, but, in my case, this recipe did work. In a way. And that's why I advice him and every newbie to do the same. I own my actual job to an app that I have installed on my android tablet - this way I could find out a job opportunity on a national announcement site. Now I work from home remotely for a business based in other city. One never know...