# Where to find contract jobs?

Tags: contracts

I am a C++ software developer. What are the best places to find a contract job (one where I am working on a fixed-length project and not working full time)? I have tried Dice, Careerbuilder, Indeed, and StackOverflow. I see a few I might be qualified for but wondering if I'm searching at the right places to begin with. I know there is also UpWork.com but I am asking more about contract jobs in the local area. Thanks!

Comment: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-to-find-clients-beyond-sites-like-odesk-guru-freelancer
http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/724/where-can-a-new-freelancer-find-people-to-work-with
http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/struggling-to-find-work/1180#1180
http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/245/how-to-approach-local-shops-to-offer-them-my-service/246#246
http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/how-to-get-direct-freelancing-work-without-job-portals